# django fucntion not subtracting the quantity selected

Tags: python, django

I have created a form that allows the user to select the item and quantity he/she wishes to purchase and upon selection I'm subtracting the pill quantity selected by the user in Item model from Stock model quantity. The problem I'm facing is that my function in views.py is only subtracting 30 even If I select 60.

```
models.py

class Item(models.Model):
    item_choices = (('Item1', 'Item1'),
        ('Item2', 'Item2'), 
        ('Item3','Item3'),
        ('Item4','Item4'),
        )

    item = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = item_choices)
    pill_choices = ((30, 30),
        (60, 60),)
    pill = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100, choices = pill_choices)

class Stock(models.Model):
    stockId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ItemID = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    Item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Item_name

   
views.py

def create_order(request):
  
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Item.objects.all()
        if item.filter(product='item1', pill=30):
            Stock.objects.filter(item_name='item1').update(quantity=F('quantity') - 30)

        elif item.filter(item='item1', pill=60):
            Stock.objects.filter(item_name='item1').update(quantity=F('quantity') - 60)


        else:
            return None

        item = form.save(commit = False)
        item.user = request.user;
        item.save()
        form = OrderForm(user=request.user)
        return redirect('/orderlist')
    context = {'form':form}
    html_form = render_to_string('order_form.html', context, request=request,
                )
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

Comment: You're not using any form values in your conditions that update `Stock`? `if item.filter(product='item1', pill=30):` uses hard-coded values but nothing user supplied

Comment: I'm really new to python

Comment: I'm confused how can I select any product from the form and the quantity then the quantity should be subtracted from the stock model objects I have created with item names each objects holding the quantity of each item

Comment: Can you add `OrderForm` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the user input value from a valid form

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
       pill = form.cleaned_data.get('pill')
       Stock.objects.filter(item_name='item1').update(quantity=F('quantity') - pill)
```

**EDIT:**
You can get the user selected item like this (same as I did with pill) and filter the Stock model based on the user selected item

```
if form.is_valid():
     pill = form.cleaned_data.get('pill')
     item = form.cleaned_data.get('item')
     Stock.objects.filter(item_name=item).update(quantity=F('quantity') - pill)
```

Comment: I have 4 products and 2 quantity choices.  I want the user to select a product and the quantity from the form select fields. Then according to the product and it's quantity selected. The quantity should be subtracted from stock model.